# Margin/Padding set to 0 - which unit is zero then?

Tags: css

Sometimes you see the margin or padding property set like this

```
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}
```

Now, while it is clear what is does, I wonder why there is no unit (cm, px, em) given. Does it have to do with the value 0 (meaning the same regardless of the unit)?

Comment: Something of nothing is nothing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`0 px;` `0 em;` `0 elephants;` All the same. All equal to nothing.

Answer (score 5):

> 0px = 0em = 0cm

They are all the same so the unit doesn't need to be specified.

See this question for more info:

[CSS Default Units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272279/css-default-units)

You should always specify the unit for values `> 0` as there is no standard default unit.

Comment: Also, you should specify the unit for values less than zero, because some things are less than nothing.

Comment: Technically in the tag attributes of images pixels is the default.  E.g. if you put width='100', that's equivalent to 100px.

Answer (score 2):

0 = 0, no matter what unit of meausurement you are using.