# How do I make a DIV stay at the top of the screen no matter ow far down the page my visitor scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What I'm saying is, I have some extremely long pages on my website, which can make it annoying if my visitors need to scroll to the top of the page to be able to navigate to another page.

I'm not quite sure what I would call this but any Google search that contains the words 'DIV' and 'float' come up with completely unrelated results...

What I'm looking to do is create a DIV that stays at the top of the ***Screen*** (not to be confused with the ***page***) so that if the user is at the bottom of the page, they can still see the navigation bar just floating at the top of the screen. What I can think of is to position the DIV relative to the position of the screen but I don't know how to code this.

I'm happy to use JavaScript (preferably in the form of jQuery), but if you know how to do this using CSS, I would favour your response.

This might help: I know a little bit of jQuery and JavaScript and I know a good deal of CSS and HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`fixed` position has exactly this purpose and this is pure CSS:

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0px instead of 0? (Is 0 a valid value?)

Comment: 0 is a valid value. Both are, but I think 0 is cleaner because 0 is 0, in px, em's, % or whatever.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help! The 'position' is one CSS code that I know only a little bit about.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272279/css-default-units, o is the only value for which  you can leave off the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="position: fixed;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [CSS Fixed Positioning](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position)

```
#eleID { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't feel left out mr. lucky Last, thank you for your input also :)