# What is the difference between height = 2px and height = 2

Tags: css, units-of-measurement

What is the difference between height = 2px and height = 2? When we don't specify units like px or em what unit does it take?

Comment: There is no "default" unit in css. Unit is required for non-zero values. So `height=2` is invalid according to css standard. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272279/css-default-units) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to HTML then it will always be pixels. If it is CSS it will be browser dependent and dependent on the element you are assigning the height to, for example line-height: 2 will represent 200% of the value of the font on that line. Current browsers assign it as an invalid value in CSS and the size should not render.

Answer (score 0):

It should not work.

If you checked the dev-tools, you'll notice this message `height: 50;`

> Invalid property value

Because you have to add units, so that the browser know how to render your element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is invalid.

You can use the chrome tools (F12) to inspect an element, remove the 'px' from it, and receive the warning of an invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

using this link try height = 100 and height = 100 px.understand the differe
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_bottom