# What is the measure unit set if there's nothing declared in the number value [ CSS ]

Tags: html, css

It's much more easy to me to explain it by simple example:

```
<img src='...'>

img {

    margin: 30;
    width: 100;
    height: 200;
}
```

If there's no px or percentage declared for margin, width and height, what would be the measure unit for it then?

Answer (score 4):

Its much more easy to explain this with a metaphor:

You wanna buy a plate for your table in a hardware store. The service guy ask you with length and width the plate should have. You say: `"100 x 200"`. His Face

The Problem is those units could be anything: mm, cm, px, apples. To go on with the metaphor, the browser now is the service guy and has absolute now clue what you mean with width: 100; and no value. Therefore he just take 0 = no margin because this is the default value for `margin`. Basically all styles that define dimensions or measurements need a value, else those are `null`.

According the W3C:

- `margin` default value: 0
- `padding` default value: 0
- `width` default value: auto
- `height` default value: auto

Hope this helps for understanding. A list with all default values can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: What about `flex:1 1`, `line-height:1`,`transform:scale(1.5)` etc.? This question is too broad.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey No it isn't. The OP asked about _"If there's no px or percentage declared for **margin, width and height**"_

Comment: Those properties are different because they also accept relative values instead of pure lengths. Therefore, the term "unit" doesn't necessarily apply to them.

Comment: *What is the measure unit set if there's nothing declared in the number value* OP mentioned those properties just for example, we should provide OP proper information, which properties needs `unit` and which not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default value, it is treated as a syntax error and that style is not applied

Please find below the screenshot highlighting this.
[image: default css unit]

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Default Units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272279/css-default-units) this question goes more in depth about the topic. 
I don't think there is a default value, just invalid statements. Pretty easy to specify units though.
The list is here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 1):

**Basic answer: Nothing**

If you don't set a unit size then the rules will be ignored.

Let's see what happens if we don't set a unit size:

```css
div {
  width: 100;
  height: 200;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly needs to be taken in context.

Eg could be z-index, or font weight, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `line-height: 1;` renders as `line-height: 1em;`