# Must use PX in CSS or it it not mandatory

Tags: css

I am confused about the use of PX after any numeric value in CSS like `width:100px;`

If I write `width:100;` instead of `width:100px;` it is also working for me so I confuse it is mandatory or not.

Comment: Its just a good practice.. There are other units too.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [CSS Default Units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272279/css-default-units)

Comment: Wouldn't use without unit. more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units

Comment: Just because something *happens to* work doesn't mean it *must* or *always will*. Write what you mean, not the bare minimum that *seems* to work right now on one browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a unit has always been mandatory. However, in Quirks mode, you can usually get away with omitting the px, since the browser's error correction will fill in the px for you. That is, usually, but not always.

In Standards mode, a length without a unit is always considered an error, and the style is not used. I therefore conclude that you must be using Quirks mode, which is not a good idea.

Here is an example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border:5 solid black">A div with border:5 solid black</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Copy this to a HTML document and load it into a browser. Some browsers will show the 5px border, others won't.
(Sorry I can't provide a link here that you can click on, since I can't find an online snippet service that won't add a doctype declaration!)

So it's best to always use a unit, even though you can find situations in which it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thank for useful info. I make more Research about it and found one conclusion that if i write with **!DOCTYPE** declaration
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border-width:5;border-style:solid;border-color:#000;">A div with border:5 solid black</div>
  </body>
</html>` Then it wont work. **without DOCTYPE** Code is run fine so i think without any unit is ok in html but it is mandatory in html5.

Comment: No, it was also illegal to leave out the `px` in HTML4. Only without any doctype whatsoever will it work. But not always; like I said, my example without a doctype has different results in different browsers, so it's best to always use a doctype and be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

It always is a good idea to declare the unit. What does 100 stands for? Apples, meters?

If you do not declare the unit of your width you given the control to your browser that is deciding what that 100 stands for.